# Hardware breakpoints on the STM32

Tags: stm32

How can I set/unset hardware breakpoints on my STM32F2 (reference manual [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf))? A search for `breakpoint` in the reference manual is less than helpful. [This document](http://www.arm.com/files/pdf/mcbstm32c_lab.pdf) suggests that my processor might have 6 hardware breakpoints.

What is the procedure for setting and removing hardware breakpoints on an STM32F2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said how you're debugging your device.
Assuming it's with gdb and OpenOCD.

```
b myfunction
```

Comment: Aha, yes! But I'm almost debugging the debugger here. I'm having a breakpoint issue (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837594/sigtrap-trace-breakpoint-trap-but-no-breakpoints-set-hidden-hardware-breakpoi)) that I would like to analyse "bare-metal", without GDB.